# MySQL SELECT discrepancy with same query - Best way to diagnose issue

Tags: mysql, select

The following SELECT returns fewer rows than expected, so I've targeted a specific employee_id to compare data.

```
SELECT SUM(tsh.entry_time) total_hr, ROUND(AVG(tsi.hourly_rate),2) AS avg_hourly, 
e.last_name, e.first_name, u.last_name AS user_last, u.first_name AS user_first
FROM timesheet ts
INNER JOIN timesheet_hours tsh ON tsh.entry_id = ts.entry_id
INNER JOIN timesheet_info tsi ON tsi.entry_id = ts.entry_id
INNER JOIN employee e on e.employee_id = ts.employee_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ts.user_id
GROUP BY ts.user_id
```

The query above returns 15 for the employee. While the following query with WHERE will return 80 rows -- which is correct.

```
SELECT SUM(tsh.entry_time) total_hr, ROUND(AVG(tsi.hourly_rate),2) AS avg_hourly, e.last_name, e.first_name, u.last_name AS user_last, u.first_name AS user_first
FROM timesheet ts
INNER JOIN timesheet_hours tsh ON tsh.entry_id = ts.entry_id
INNER JOIN timesheet_info tsi ON tsi.entry_id = ts.entry_id
INNER JOIN employee e on e.employee_id = ts.employee_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ts.user_id
WHERE e.employee_id = 4444
GROUP BY ts.user_id
```

Could server resources be the culprit? The query isn't that intensive and the result should be less than 2000 rows. Nothing massive.

What is the best way to diagnose an issue like this?

Comment: Your first query is invalid, beacuse it is using `GROUP BY user_id` but also selects other non aggregate columns.

Comment: So in order to aggregate properly in the first it'll need a subquery?

Comment: every column that is not in the group by needs a aggregation function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Yeah, this was solved by making sure they were included. Needed to group by multiple columns to get the correct output ```GROUP BY ts.user_id, e.employee_id```